# Unittest for invoking a TKinter GUI

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, user-interface, tkinter

Assume a script that initiates a TKinter GUI (e.g., `scripts/launch_GUI.py`) and is part of a PyPI package (e.g., `MyPackage`).

```
.
├── appveyor.yml
├── MyPackage
│   ├── TkOps.py
│   └── CoreFunctions.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── scripts
│   ├── launch_CLI.py
│   └── launch_GUI.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── MyPackage_test.py
```

The launch script is very minimalistic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys, os
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'MyPackage'))
    import TkOps
    TkOps.start_GUI()
```

What *unittest* would you recommend to evaluate if the TKinter GUI is properly started upon initiating `launch_GUI.py`?

**Note**: I only wish to evaluate if the launch script does its work and launches the GUI, not if a user can interact with the GUI.

Comment: Can't you check the `state()` of the window?

Comment: @TeeKea Can you explain this further? I am unaware of the function `state` and cannot seem to find any info on it: `>>> import tkinter   >>> help("state")   no Python documentation found for 'state'`

Comment: Please have a look at the following link. I guess you can check if the is `state()` is `'normal`. Can you show some of your code you used for creating the top level window?' http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.state-method

Comment: what does your start_GUI() function do? does it create an object? if so: why not test the type of the object, if it's a <class 'tkinter.Tk'> then you know it started a tk window at the very least. for example, typing following command in a python interpreter window will output above mentioned result.: "import tkinter as tk; root=tk.Tk(); type(root)"

Comment: above comment was getting bulky: in suggested command I implicitly created the root object as a tkinter window, then called type() to confirm the type of my root object. if your function creates a tkinter window as an object, you should be able to check it's type, confirming it was created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be argued that you'd need a **functional** test rather than a **unit** test, but let's try this anyway!

While it's possible to test launch script as is via `exec()`, it's considered bad practice. Let's refactor it:

```
def main():
    import sys, os
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'MyPackage'))
    import TkOps
    TkOps.start_GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then let's establish what the unit test should test, for example:

- `sys.path` is updated with the correct path for `MyPackage`
- `start_GUI` is called

Then a **mokist** [1] unit test could look like this:

```
@mock.patch("sys.path", copy.copy(sys.path))
@mock.patch.dict(sys.modules, TkOps=mock.MagicMock())
def test_main():
    main()
    # minimal validation of sys.path side effect
    # ideally this would check that path bit points to real directory
    assert any(p.endswith("/MyPackage") for p in sys.path)
    # validation of expected call
    assert sys.modules["TkOps"].start_GUI.called
```

A **classical** unit test would require an escape hatch in the GUI, for example:

```
def start_GUI(dry_run=False):
    import tk
    ...
    if not dry_run: tk.foobar()
```

[1] https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2015/04/18/classical-vs-mockist-testing/

Comment: Thanks for this sophisticated answer. I will need some time to understand it all.

Comment: could you share the imports of explanatory test and what is necessary from pypi to execute? Then youll have a thumps up ;)